# How to run Apache Spark applications with a JAR dependency from AWS S3?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a `.jar` file containing useful functions for my application located in an AWS S3 bucket, and I want to use it as a dependency in Spark without having to first download it locally. Is it possible to directly reference the `.jar` file with `spark-submit` (or `pyspark`) `--jars` option?

So far, I have tried the following:

```bash
spark-shell --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.336,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4 --jars s3a://bucket/path/to/jar/file.jar
```

The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` variables are correctly set, since when running the same command without the `--jars` option, other files in the same bucket are successfully read. However, if the option is added, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    ... 27 more
```

I'm using Spark 3.3.1 pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.3 and later.

Comment: The way is correct I think the problem is with org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws dependency not getting resolved properly.

Comment: Is it a version mismatch? Reading data from S3 inside the application (e.g. `spark.read.parquet("s3a://path/to/file.parquet")`) works just fine, so I think it should be working.

Comment: Just realized you're using client mode, and with client mode only local paths work

Comment: Added my answer based on observation, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be because when in client mode - Spark during its boot distributes the Jars (specified in --jars) via Netty first. To download a remote JAR from a third-party file system (i.e. S3), it'll need the right dependency (i.e. hadoop-aws) in the classpath already (before it prepares the final classpath).

But since it is yet to distribute the JARs it has not prepared the classpath - thus when it tries to download the JAR from s3, it fails with ClassNotFound (as hadoop-aws is yet to be on the classpath), but when doing the same in the application code it succeeds - as by that time the classpath has been resolved.

**i.e. Downloading the dependency is dependent on a library that will be loaded later.**

Comment: So, I'd have to add hadoop-aws to the classpath _before_ running spark? What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: @PiFace You won't be able to do that with Spark-submit. Instead as an alternative you can download the Jar locally and use --jars with local URI or place the Jar in the cluster manually or try with Cluster Mode.

Comment: * spark-submit and maven coordinates.
 
If you have only one JAR I would recommend just having it locally. If not, then download the Hadoop-aws jar and use extraClassPath. Check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-spark-classnotfoundexception/

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing out this information.

Comment: @PiFace Glad! Let me know if you need help with the same,